# Making Production database as Publisher and Distributor for Snasphot Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, snapshot, hadr

In our environment we are using Log Shipping as DR. Our primary database is a  clustered instance. My requirement is to set up a snapshot replication for reporting purposes.

My plan is as follows:

1. Make the production database as the distributor and publisher.
2. The subscriber will be a read only for reporting.

My question is:

Will there be any problem if the production database acts both as distributor and subscriber?

Comment: U mean `will there be any problem if the production db acts both as Distributor and Subscribor` as `will there be any problem if the production db acts both as Distributor and Publisher` ? It depends on how busy is the publisher publishing data e.g. amount of transactions on publisher. If its low volume then should be fine.

Comment: This will be a busy server  but I will be using snapshot replication where only once a day it replicates

Comment: How big is the database ?

Comment: Currently 60gb but it will increase yearly around 30 gb

Comment: Then instead of going through all the hassel of replication why not backup/restore with compression or just delay the log restores and open the db for reporting ?

Comment: I had the log shipped server in mind. Currently it restores every 15 minutes . I can delay to every 6 hours and during failover i will just need to run the restore job to make it current and failover. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your hardware. I've seen a table in the 70GB range take approximately 20 minutes to create a snapshot. Longer on older hardware. If anything else is being done, it can result in blocking.

If you write the snapshot files to the same drives as your database files then it will create I/O contention and can impact performance. And saturate your network bandwidth.

But the same can happen if you have a separate distributor as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I beleive using the same server for distributor and subscriber will release some load from the publication database.

Comment: I would then configure separate disks for the snapshot files and database files

Answer (score 2):

Since your database is 100GB, you can use backup and restore method with compression (make sure Instant file Initialization is enabled).

Another approach will be to use logshipping with delaying the restoring of log files on the standby server and having the database in standby read mode ( WITH STANDBY).

The way you do is -

- take your regular log backups on your primary (in your case every 15 mins)
- keep the copy job as is to copy log files to network share.
- Choose the option to delay the restoring of logs as per your threshold.
- To [speed up restoring the logs](https://troubleshootingsql.com/2012/09/11/get-your-log-shipping-restore-to-run-faster/) - change the setting of logshipping to `norecovery`
- once done restoring the logs, change it back to `standby`.

If you want to automate the entire process, use d[batools - Log Shipping functions/cmdlets](https://dbatools.io/functions/)